# .hover() works, but not for each individual item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I am trying to make a button appear on hover and disappear when the mouse moves away from the object. There are lots of posts, like you might find on the Twitter feed but I only want the button to appear on the post you're hovering over, not all of them. Here is my code:

```
$(".posts").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("article .report-post").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).find("article .report-post .report-btn").css('visibility', 'visible');
}, function () {   
    $(this).find("article .report-post").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).find("article .report-post .report-btn").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

What am I doing wrong? If I do this, nothing happens:

```
$("article").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".report-post").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).find(".report-post .report-btn").css('visibility', 'visible');
}, function () {   
    $(this).find(".report-post").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).find(".report-post .report-btn").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Is that perhaps because there are lots of `<article>`s on the webpage?

**EDIT**: Here is the HTML of one of the `<article>`s:

```
<article class="single-post">
    <div class="profile-pic">
        <a href="tg">
        <div style="background-image:url(example.jpg);background-size:cover;width:70px;height:70px;"></div></a>
    </div><!-- profile-pic -->

    <div class="text">
        <h5 class="tg" id="CMfQ34erT6-author"><a href="tg" style="color:#2C3E50;">Tristram Gale</a></h5><a class="report-post" href="#" id="CMfQ34erT6" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <div class="report-btn" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></a>

        <p class="post-text">LALALALALALALALALALALA</p>

        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li style="text-overflow: ellipsis;width: 170px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;">
                    <a href="school.php?id=1">Devonport High School for Boys</a>
                </li>

                <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
                    <a href="post.php?id=CMfQ34erT6">
                    <ul>
                        <li title="2013-07-02 21:16:57">about 15 hours ago</li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="comments" id="CMfQ34erT6">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">0 comments</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="comments-box" id="CMfQ34erT6-box" style="display: none;">
            <div id="CMfQ34erT6-comment-box">
                <ul>
                    <li class="CMfQ34erT6-new-comment">
                        <form class="CMfQ34erT6-form" id="CMfQ34erT6" name="CMfQ34erT6">
                            <input autocomplete="off" id="newCommentText" placeholder="Write a comment..." type="text"><input id="addcomment" onclick="return postComment(this.form.id, this.form.newCommentText.value)" type="button" value="Post">
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- text -->

    <div class="clear"></div><!-- clear -->
</article>
```

Thanks

Comment: post html and css code also

Comment: What is the doctype? Note, this effect can be achieved in pure CSS3.

Comment: jsfiddle will be nice

Comment: what about hide/show jquery's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not planning to use the `hover()` functions for something else in Javascript you can do it completely in CSS.

Remove the `style="visibility: hidden;"` attributes from the button and link and add this to your CSS:

```
article .report-post {
    visibility: hidden;
}
article:hover .report-post {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The button will only be visible as long as the cursor is over the article.

jsfiddle is online again: http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/6MQv7/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've tested this on jsfiddle but their server is down now - see http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/jsfiddle.net.html
In HTML change the style attribute from `visibility:hidden` to `display:none` for `div` and `a` as well.

And then the following code works:

```
$(".posts .single-post").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".report-post").show();
    $(this).find(".report-btn").show();
}, function () {   
    $(this).find(".report-post").hide();
    $(this).find(".report-btn").hide();
});
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't do a thing :( really strange

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

1. Make sure you've put the hover() function inside document.ready()
2. There was no text inside the class .report-btn. Make sure you can see the button, when everything is set to visible.
3. There is no need of the .find, make it simple...

for eg, try this code:

```
$(function() { 
$('article').hover(function() {
    $(".report-post").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(".report-post .report-btn").css('visibility', 'visible');
}, function () {   
    $(".report-post").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(".report-post .report-btn").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
});
```

If it still doesn't work, try the "display:none" and the "display:block" instead of the "visibility"

Comment: I have done both of those things, but still, nothing happens.

Comment: Is the .report-btn visible when you remove the jquery and set its visibility to visible?(Since there was no text in your button in the .report-btn class). I used this function(after adding some text in the .report-btn div) and it worked for me.

Comment: Can we chat about this privately? I can give you access to the site so you can see it for yourself. The .report-btn does show when I change the visibility manually, yes. But the code above still doesn't work. If you can email me at js.anderson@icloud.com, that would be very much appreciated. Thanks.